# Recarregar todo css dentro de um div

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-5

Caros, vou tentar explicar meu problema, espero ser claro.

Estou usando C# MVC5 em minha app.

Hoje tenho uma pagina e nela um grid. Nesse grid existe um botão de editar o registro.

Ao clicar nesse botão, eu abro um modal e nele exibo um formulario com os dados a serem editados.

Eu uso ajax para que o conteudo do modal seja criado dinamicamente, conforme codigo abaixo.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(linkText: "Clique Aqui", 
                actionName: "Editar", 
                ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "modal", 
                                                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter })

<div id="modal"></div>
```

O que acontece é que, ao clicar, ele gera o conteudo do form e "coloca" dentro do div "modal".
Até aqui, tudo certo. O problema acontece que como o conteudo é adicionado via ajax, ou seja, depois que a pagina ja foi carregada, eu perco o css "pedaço" da pagina, apenas parte do funciona.

Tenho um  dentro do form, e ele por exemplo não "herda" o css.

Se eu coloco o HTML dentro da pagina, sem ser por ajax funciona, mas eu preciso que seja feito via ajax.

Então pergunto: Como posso fazer um reload do CSS ou forçar que esse novo "pedaço" de HTML inserido no fonte, utilize-se do css e jquery por completo?

---

O HTML inserido é esse:

```
<form action="/CedenteDocumentos/Edit/1" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="qshEjMnv9StRE3qk5uBu1VJ6rUuxvyl_b06t0kD3nE2ykez2IXWEBqXiqD3_XLQBvo92q0ExL9iY3HbG0s3dVN7Zd8UMWgsDAzGDvAm3D6o1">    <div class="modal-content">

    <input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col l8">
            <input class="validate text-box single-line" id="nome" name="Nome" placeholder=" " type="text" value="Documento 144444">
            <label for="Nome">Documento</label>
        </div>


    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col l6">
            <select data-val="true" data-val-required="The Grupo field is required." htmlattributes="{ value = 0 }" id="Grupo" name="Grupo"><option value="">Selecione</option>
```

Empresa
Sócios
Representantes

                Grupo

```
        <div class="input-field col l2" style="margin-top: -5px; margin-left: -10px;">
            <input type="checkbox" id="ativo" name="ativo" class="filled-in" checked="checked" value="1">
            <label for="ativo">Ativo</label>
        </div>


    </div>

    <div class="row">




        <div class="row">
            <div class="col l10" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                <button class="btn-floating btn-sm waves-effect waves-light green darken-1 right" style="transform: scale(1)" type="submit" name="action" title="Salvar">
                    <i class="mdi-action-done"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Se eu coloco esse codigo "na mao" ou seja, sem que seja inserido com ajax, ele funciona perfeitamente, mas quando coloco via ajax, parte do CSS não funciona.

Comment: Ao adicionar novos elementos a uma página, automáticamente eles tem acesso a todas as regras do CSS e acesso as funções do jQuery. Logo, deveria funcionar normalmente. Adicione à pergunta o conteúdo que é adicionado ao div modal e os estilos que deveriam ser aplicados a esses elementos, assim podemos te ajudar.

Comment: A inserção de HTML está levando em consideração todas as classes e seletores que seu CSS usa?